# Можно ли в regex.findall() найти с одной строки по другую?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

Можно ли в python 2.7 в regex.findall() найти допустим с одной строки по другую?
У меня вот есть дата, которую мне надо перебрать с regex.

> UA.E.3858-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",RENAULT CLIO,M1,,2013,VF17R040H49534950,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zT0V0YlZINGRsSFU,
> UA.E.3859-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",NISSAN MICRA,M1,,2012,MDHFBUK13U0522453,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zV3RwLXlmdzk0dkE,
> UA.E.3860-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",CITROEN BERLINGO,N1,,2011,VF77N9HP0BJ654851,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zODZpSGI5REVza3c,
> UA.E.3861-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",NISSAN LEAF,M1,,2015,1N4AZ0CP9FC323172,б/к,ЕЛ,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zejkxNFN0WXhhSUk,
> UA.E.3862-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",FIAT DOBLO,M1,,2010,ZFA26300009062099,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zVkNQMERFR21XOGc,
> UA.E.3863-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",AUDI S5 SPORTBACK,M1,,2012,WAUZZZ8T2CA027101,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zSzVRa3VMcHVXVVE,
> UA.E.3864-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",OPEL VIVARO,N1,,2013,W0LF7B1BEDV610630,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zRmR2amNBSDJkRWs,
> UA.E.3865-17,23.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",SKODA FABIA,M1,,2011,TMBEM25J6B3178665,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zaW9VdHJ1MTZUTGc,
> UA.E.3870-17,24.05.2017,"ДП ""Укрметртестстандарт""",NISSAN QUASHQAI,M1,,2013,SJNFEAJ10U2704476,б/к,Євро-5,,https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B48-MrZcy1-zM1BGcFhJLTZ0T00,

Мне нужно с "UA" перебрать до спец символа "\n".
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы на выходе я получил каждый этот кусочек текста с UA до \n в разных переменных. Первый кусочек в первой переменной, второй во второй...

Comment: `re.findall(r'UA([^\n]+)\n', s, re.S & re.M)` ?

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Не получается скачать по этой ссылке https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=11WR6rwQhL4wUDN8I77ju_5rzZl8IglsUjtUDI6pZsAQ&output=csv

Comment: Измените ваш вопрос, чтобы он был более понятен: опишите более подробно какой результат вы хотите получить и что вы уже пытались сделать. Есть ли возможность использовать другие модули и если нет, то почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

url = r'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=11WR6rwQhL4wUDN8I77ju_5rzZl8IglsUjtUDI6pZsAQ&output=csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=28, header=None)
```

Результат:

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
                    0           1                            2                        3    4                 5     6   \
0      UA.A(b).0023-16  29.01.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"                     MINI   M1               NaN   NaN
1      UA.A(b).0024-16  29.01.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"                     MINI   M1               NaN   NaN
2      UA.A(b).0025-16  29.01.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"                     MINI   M1               NaN   NaN
3      UA.A(b).0028-16  29.01.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"   Mercedes-Benz AMG G 63  M1G               NaN   NaN
4      UA.A(b).0032-16  29.01.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"                      NaN    -  CHANGFENG, HIFLY   NaN
5      UA.A(b).0034-16  02.02.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"  FFB Feldbinder TSA 30.3   O4               NaN   NaN
6      UA.A(b).0035-16  02.02.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"        DAF FT XF 105.460   N3               NaN   NaN
7      UA.A(b).0036-16  02.02.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"             Krone SDP 27   O4               NaN   NaN
8      UA.A(b).0038-16  02.02.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"              SKODA RAPID   M1               NaN   NaN
9      UA.A(b).0027-16  03.02.2016  ДП "ДержавтотрансНДІпроект"    Mercedes-AMG AMG GT S   M1               NaN   NaN
...                ...         ...                          ...                      ...  ...               ...   ...
83771     UA.E.3857-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"              DACIA LODGY   M1               NaN  2014
83772     UA.E.3858-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"             RENAULT CLIO   M1               NaN  2013
83773     UA.E.3859-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"             NISSAN MICRA   M1               NaN  2012
83774     UA.E.3860-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"         CITROEN BERLINGO   N1               NaN  2011
83775     UA.E.3861-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"              NISSAN LEAF   M1               NaN  2015
83776     UA.E.3862-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"               FIAT DOBLO   M1               NaN  2010
83777     UA.E.3863-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"        AUDI S5 SPORTBACK   M1               NaN  2012
83778     UA.E.3864-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"              OPEL VIVARO   N1               NaN  2013
83779     UA.E.3865-17  23.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"              SKODA FABIA   M1               NaN  2011
83780     UA.E.3870-17  24.05.2017     ДП "Укрметртестстандарт"          NISSAN QUASHQAI   M1               NaN  2013

                                  7      8       9    10                             11   12
0                  WMWXS71020T843838  новий  Євро-6  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
1                  WMWXS510402D48540  новий  Євро-6  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
2                  WMWXS510X02D48509  новий  Євро-6  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
3                  WDB4632721X249338  новий  Євро-6  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
4      270 од., інвойс №15HFTD010...    NaN       -  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
5                  WFB334S9BG0052729  новий       -  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
6                  XLRTE47MS0E808234    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
7                  WKESDP27061270299    б/к       -  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
8                  TMBAF6NH4G4020744  новий  Євро-6  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
9                  WMX1903781A008268  новий  Євро-6  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
...                              ...    ...     ...  ...                            ...  ...
83771              UU1JSDB3551390677    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83772              VF17R040H49534950    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83773              MDHFBUK13U0522453    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83774              VF77N9HP0BJ654851    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83775              1N4AZ0CP9FC323172    б/к      ЕЛ  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83776              ZFA26300009062099    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83777              WAUZZZ8T2CA027101    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83778              W0LF7B1BEDV610630    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83779              TMBEM25J6B3178665    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN
83780              SJNFEAJ10U2704476    б/к  Євро-5  NaN  https://drive.google.com/o...  NaN

[83781 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: Я сохраняю в питоне данные с гугл таблицы и не скачиваю дату, мне нужно, чтобы с regex и for каждый UA до \n был присвоен каждой переменной

Comment: Есть еще другие модули?

Comment: @DanTheMan, наверняка есть другие модули, которые позволяют сделать тоже самое. Просто в Pandas это делается очень просто и максимально эффективно

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что тут можно будет подобрать хороший паттерн для регулярок. Лучше попробовать другие модули.

Если у вас csv формат, вы можете воспользоваться модулем [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Если вы не хотите сохранять данные, думаю, он будет более предпочтителен для вас, ибо с помощью него можно будет пропарсить просто `string` переменную.

Но также разбить файл по разделителю можно и без csv модуля. Достаточно просто использовать функцию `split()` к переменной типа `string`.

```
for line in lines:
    splitted = line.split(',') # по умолчанию разделение идёт по пробелу
    # код далее
```

`split` можно использовать и при чтении файла:

```
with open ('filename.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip() # или rstrip(), чтобы убрать спец символы типа \n, \t и т.п.
        splitted = line.split(',')
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое